# Select JVM when running spark job

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

How can I pass java path to spark-submit to select JVM that is not default (not in JAVA_HOME)? I am not allowed to set any env vars in my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems using SPARK_YARN_USER_ENV is one of the ways to solve the issue. Also, it seems setExecutorEnv can be used for this, but I didn't try.

Answer (score 0):

http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/configuration.html

see the section Environment Variables.

Comment: Well, as I stated I'd like to avoid setting JAVA_HOME explicitly.

Comment: how about adding it to the spark config file?

Comment: Well, I've tried setting JAVA_HOME explicitly, but it seems executors take default JAVA_HOME anyway (defined in bashrc for user that is the root for hadoop/spark), so I wonder if there is actually any way to pass JAVA_HOME to executors?